# IOBluetoothDevice register doesn't work with forConnectNotifications

Tags: swift, macos, iobluetooth

I have a Bluetooth device already selected and I am trying to register connect and disconnect notifications

```
func selectDevice() {
    var promptRes = Int32?((deviceSelector?.runModal())!)
    if promptRes == Int32(kIOBluetoothUISuccess) {
        self.selectedDevice = deviceSelector?.getResults().first as? IOBluetoothDevice
        selectedDevice?
            .register(forConnectNotifications: self, selector: #selector(connected))
        selectedDevice?
            .register(forDisconnectNotification: self, selector: #selector(disconnected))
        self.connectDevice()
    } else {
        self.selectedDevice = nil
    }
}
```

I haven't problems with the `forDisconnectNotification`but I get next error with the `forConnectNotifications`:

`Incorrect argument label in call (have 'forConnectNotifications:selector:', expected 'forDisconnectNotification:selector:')`

[image]

It's so strange because even in the official doc it is documented `forConnectNotifications` instead of `forDisconnectNotification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the `forDisconnectNotification` can be associated with the instance https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth/iobluetoothdevice/1429542-register but the `forConnectNotifications` must be associated with the type https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth/iobluetoothdevice/1433370-register.

This one is the proper way to implement it
            IOBluetoothDevice.register(forConnectNotifications: self, selector: #selector(connected))